# Alexa - Perform background tasks during audioPlayer.Play

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

How is it possible to carry out any background tasks while Alexa is playing something with audioPlayer.Play?

The below plays an audio stream, but I need to perform other tasks in the background without intervention while the stream is playing. I know it is possible because other Skills can do it.

```
var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit('Play');        
  },

  'Play': function() {   

    this.response.speak('Sure.').
    audioPlayerPlay(
        'REPLACE_ALL', 
        stream.url, 
        stream.url, 
        null, 
        0);

    this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know or have any suggestions? From what I can see, once it starts playing the stream, I cannot get it to do anything unless I interrupt the stream to command another intent?

Answer (score 0):

Alexa has a few built in requests that she sends to your skill throughout the lifecycle of an Audio stream for just this purpose! They are as follows:

1. AudioPlayer.PlaybackStarted - Sent when a new audio item begins playing.
2. AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished - Sent when an audio item is almost over (most commonly used by a skill service to handle queuing the next item.)
3. AudioPlayer.PlaybackFinished - Sent when an audio item ends.

There are a couple of other ones too that you can read about [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html#playbackstarted), but my guess is these will do just fine for what you need.

To use them, just set up handlers in your code for any of these requests and perform any tasks you need to there!

I don't know node.js at all, but my guess is the end result will look relatively close to this:

```
var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() { /* your launch request code from above */ }
  'Play': function() { /* your play code from above */ }
  'AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished': function() { 
    // Perform any background tasks here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried this yet, but does the AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished only work when the playback is going to end? As this is a continuous (live) stream, surely (PlaybackNearlyFinished) this will never be invoked because the stream never ends?

Comment: @omega1 Yeah as far as I know it only triggers near the end of each audio item so if you‘re only streaming one item it won’t send. But if that is the case you could just switch my example to use the PlaybackStarted request and do everything you need there.